# Bootstrap vertical spacing on mobile

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-5

I have a bootstrap breadcrumb element with a page header on the same row which works fine on large monitors but on mobile the header covers the breadcrumb. How do I force the header to a new row for smaller screens?

```
 <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body d-lg-flex align-items-center">
        <nav class="mb-3 mb-lg-0">
            <ol class="breadcrumb mb-0">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                    <a href="Default.aspx">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active">This Page</li>
            </ol>
        </nav>
    </div>
   
    <div class="align-self-end align-self-md-center center-y">
        <asp:Label ID="lblHeader" runat="server" CssClass="h2 text-primary" Text="Header Text"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap's grid system to force the header to a new row on smaller screens. One way to achieve this is to wrap the breadcrumb and the header in separate div elements with the class of row, and then give each div a class of col-lg-* and col-md-* for the larger screens and col-* for smaller screens. For example:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-12">
            <nav class="mb-3 mb-lg-0">
                <ol class="breadcrumb mb-0">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                        <a href="Default.aspx">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">This Page</li>
                </ol>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-12">
            <asp:Label ID="lblHeader" runat="server" CssClass="h2 text-primary" Text="Header Text"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This way on larger screens the breadcrumb and header will be on the same line, but on smaller screens the header will be on a new row, thus avoiding the overlap.